# Filling an array[m][n] with sum of elements at m==n

Tags: c++, arrays

I need your help.

I got this interesting problem, looks more like homework, but it is really complicated.

I need to fill the elements in this array of numbers where, given certain list of numbers, I need to put them in the diagonals of the array, and then, fill the rest of positions with the sumatory of the initial numbers, I think I could explain way better if I give an example:

Numbers of the array: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -1

The Array is fill with these numbers: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

La array[n][m] is:

**7**   13 18   22   25   27   28

13    **6**   11   15   18   20   21

18   11    **5**    9   12   14   15

22   15    9    **4**    7    9   10

25   18   12    7    **3**    5    6

27   20   14    9    5    **2**    3

28   21   15   10    6    3    **1**

I tried a long of ways to do it, in c++:

```
//Here is the simple thing, setting the diagonals of the array[m][n]
for(int row=0; row < maxNumber; fila++){
    for(int column=0; column < maxNumber; column++)
    {
        if(row == column)
        {
            matAuto[row][column] = elements[row];
        }
    }
 }
```

I was trying to make a temporary array with the elements of the array, and in the loop, sum the numbers according with their positions, you know like bubble sort (array[m][n] = listNum[n] + listNum[n+1]

```
  if(row < column)
  { 
     matAuto[row][column] = elements[row] + elements[row+1];
  }

  if(row < column)
  { 
     matAuto[row][column] = elements[column] + elements[column+1];
  }

  if(row < column)
  { 
     matAuto[row][column] = elements[column] + elements[row+1];
  }

  if(row < column)
  { 
     matAuto[row][column] = matAuto[row][column] + matAuto[row+1][column+1];
  }
```

And so...nothing worth it.

I don't know if is right to add the complete code, is not long, but well, Is just the common C++ stuff, but I got it in spanish, hope it doesn't botter you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Makketronix mentioned, you can use the fact that your two triangular matrices are symmetrical.

```
for(int row=0; row < maxNumber; row++){
  for(int column=row; column < maxNumber; column++)
  {
    if(row == column)
    {
        matAuto[row][column] = elements[row];
    }
    else
    {
      int newSum = matAuto[row][column-1] + elements[column];

      // assign with mirror
      matAuto[row][column] = newSum;
      matAuto[column][row] = newSum;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, work like a charm, never thought about column taking the value of row, but now watching the code working, it does make sense, cool, thanks for all guys!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to solve half  of it and put same number in the mirror image by changing the indices.

You can do this:

- fill the diagonal
- Loop through rows: r = 1 -> colmax -1 //square matrix!

  - Loop c = r -> colmax-1 times again
  - set value at [c][c+1] = [c][c-1] + [c][c+1]

The index at [c][c+1] runs parallel to the diagonal with offset r.

The index at [c][c-1] is is the previous value in the row

The index at [c+1][c+1] is the next value in the column

After you are done, fill the other half by copying what you calculated.

Something like that.